# Can anyone see my files on the same network?

Tags: passwords, wifi

If someone hack my WiFi or they know the password . Can they see or will have access to any of my data stored in my pc connect on  the same network. Or can they control my pc or download anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing your wifi network does not automatically give anyone access to your computer or any other device on your network. Your devices are protected by their own passwords.

They might be able to attack and break your computer and gain that kind of access, but your computer would need a weakness and someone would have to exploit it.

If you want to share your WiFi, a lot of wifi routers have a "guest" network that you can set up, and they can't even see your home devices.

Answer (score -1):

It depends upon the situation. If the attacker is on your network and has good penetration testing skills, he can easily penetrate into your PC.

Basic precautions would be:

1. You should disable the network share access of your pc.
2. You should disable the remote desktop connection of your pc.
3. You also should have to disable the Powershell process in order to  prevent remote code execution.

However, after taking all the safety measures the hacker could still possibly intrude into your PC through taking the advantage vulnerabilities in your Windows Operating System. For that, you have to update/patch Windows.

After taking all the safety measures, there will be more than 75% chance that no one will able to intrude into your system.

Comment: Why Powershell? Powershell is not exposed to the network

Comment: What is your basis for the 75% level? Don't try to quantify without some way to measure.

Comment: You start with saying that it is "easy", then at the end say that it is difficult. I think you could take another attempt at this answer

Comment: Powershell is used in the callback initiation through the network and i believe that you know that. in case someones intrudes so this tactic for the prevention will be useful.

Comment: As per you objectification on the quantification is have to say that is not mandatory in every situation to define someone on the exact principal as assumption i have used that 75% level to make the non technical person understand ... i believe next time you will not get offensive with my answers :)

Comment: You better read the answer first then objectify in what sense i have said for the easiness and difficulties in my answer.

Comment: "Basic precautions to prevent penetration" should not include disabling Powershell. Disabling PS is a post-exploitation defence. It does not belong on a list for preventing remote access. And no, it is not easy to break into a Windows box. Once you patch, and close services, as you suggest, the difficulty is not 75% (which is an arbitrary number without explanation, by your own admission), it's much closer to 99%. It's very difficult. The difficulty of this is tested quite often.